# checkbox is always "on"

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, uploadify

Hy!

When Uploadify send the file to the action, I need to know if the checbox is checked or not, so I did:

```
    $('#uploaded').uploadify({
        'uploader': '/uploadify.swf',
        'cancelImg': '/cancel.png',
        'script': '/Interaction/Upload',
        'multi': true,
        'auto': false,
        'method': 'post',
        'scriptData': {'Checkbox': $('#checkbox').val()},
    });
```

But I aways get an "on" value. No matter if is checked or not.

can anyone help? Tks.

---

**UPDATE:**

I realized that uploadify is getting the checkbox when the page is loaded.This means that if I change the checkbox (or any other type of input) the uploadify will get the initial value, in this case, "checkbox = false".

How can I send a form with uploadify?

Tks.

Answer (score 71):

try `$('#checkbox').is(':checked')`

Comment: I'm getting always "false" using this to.

Answer (score 32):

A checkbox's value is always 'on'. The HTML Form sends the value to the server only if the checkbox is checked. If the box is not checked, then the request parameter will be absent. This semantics is apparently to minimize the differences between checkboxes and radio buttons.

The HTML Form implements the following semantics:

```
if ($('#mycheckbox').is(':checked')) {
    payload['mycheckbox'] = $('#mycheckbox').val();
}
```

You can either mimic this semantics in Ajax or send the 'checked' flag directly as follows:

```
payload['mycheckbox'] = $('#mycheckbox').is(':checked');
```

I'd recommend mimic'ing the HTML Form semantics. Irrespective of what the client does, I'd recommend the following in the server code:

```
if mycheckbox param exists and its value is either 'true' or 'on' {  // pseudo code of course
    // mycheckbox is checked
} else {
    // mycheckbox is unchecked
}
```

Hope this explanation helps.

Comment: The on semantics are very confusing... I hope it made someone's life easier!  Even a disabled checkbox has a value of "on"...

Comment: Very confusing implementation - but this answer helped me understand why val() always returns 'on' for checkboxes.

Comment: What to do if `('form').serializeArray(data)` is used?

Answer (score 21):

There is a pretty handy way to check all these element properties like `disabled`, `checked`, etc. with the `prop` function. This also converts it to boolean:

```
$('#checkbox').prop('checked'); // -> true/false
$('#checkbox').prop('disabled'); // -> true/false
```

Comment: wtf @chx101! what do you want from me? :P :D

Comment: Vanilla JS: var isChecked = elDom.checked // _> true/false

Answer (score 12):

Try this

```
$('#checkbox').is(':checked')
```

Comment: I like how this method gives you a boolean.

Answer (score 7):

Change:

```
$('#checkbox').val()
```

to

```
$('#checkbox').attr('checked')
```

Comment: I'm getting always "false". I don't know why.

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same problem and found this solution:

```
if($("input[name='yourcheckbox']").is(':checked')) {
   console.log('chb checked');
} else {
   console.log('chb not checked');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

var checkboxValue = $('#id').prop('checked');

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$('#checkbox').attr('checked')
```

Answer (score -1):

You can give

if(jQuery(this).attr('checked')){
// u have to use this selector according to your function it may be .click .live or else..

Thanks